# Convert a query from MySql to SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Please help to change the below MySQL query to SQLite

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT t.arabic_term AS t__1,
    SUBSTR(t.definition, 1, 60) AS Definition,
    Sum(if(t3.is_main="y", 1 ,0)) AS t3__5
FROM term t 
INNER JOIN term_disease t2 ON (t2.disease_id = t.term_id) 
INNER JOIN term_disease_symptom t3 ON (t3.disease_id = t2.disease_id)
WHERE (t3.symptom_id in ( 45378 , 45351, 5546 ) AND t2.gender != 1  AND t2.active = 1 )
GROUP BY t3.disease_id
ORDER BY t3__5  desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below

```
Sum(if(t3.is_main="y", 1 ,0)) AS t3__5
```

sould be replaced with

```
SUM(CASE t3.is_main WHEN 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS t3__5
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not have an `IF` function, but boolean expression are defined as having the values 1 or 0.
So that particular expression would be:

```
SUM(t3.is_main = 'y') AS t3__5
```

Anything else is standard SQL.

Comment: In SQLite, the expression `t3.is_main = 'y'` already _is_ 0 or 1.